# Download file by ajax with header 'X-ACCESS-TOKEN' to authenticate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Download API is using 'X-ACCESS-TOKEN' in header to authentiate,so i want download it throught by ajax to set header,but not work. Please tell me how can do it?

My code :

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: api_url+"/download",
    data: {file_id: '112dsfsd'},
    headers: {'X-ACCESS-TOKEN': 'dag327928'},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        //do something
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Some more information and some code would help

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an accepted question. Please provide your code and the details of what you expect it to do, and what happens exactly (including exact output, errors, etc.).

Comment: This still doesn't tell us what *you* are running into. It's like a person going to a doctor and not telling them any of their symptoms. Add any errors that are showing up in the console. If none are, print `data` from your error function, and post that.

Comment: Again, tell us what you expect it to do, and what actually happens. Tell us what shows up in the logs.